# What does the word "staff" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, collective-nouns

These are some sentences from dictionaries with the word "staff":

> Cambridge dictionary:
> There are over a hundred staff in the company.

> Oxford dictionary:
> the pending lay-off of fifty staff

Why is it fifty or a hundred staff and not "members" of the staff? I thought that staff means:

> (Professions) a group of people employed by a company, individual, etc, for executive, clerical, sales work, etc (source: [Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/staff))

but these sentences are talking about fifty and a hundred individuals, right?

Comment: You can read **staff** to mean **members of staff**

Comment: The very first definition in the Cambridge Dictionary - the one with the example that you quoted-  states  [S, + sing/ **pl** verb ]. I agree that that's a bit cryptic, but it shows that staff is always singlular (ie not staffs) even when used with a plural verb or (as in the example that you quoted) when a number is specified. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/staff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top few definitions at The Free Dictionary don't mention the plural form "staff". [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/staff) makes clear that when "staff" has this meaning, the plural form is "staff":

> e *plural* **staff** : a member of a staff
> // employs three full-time *staff*

Comment: The definition listed is actually one of many on that page, including ones covered in your answer. The Free Dictionary is actually a compilation of several credible dictionaries.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, there are some definitions lower down that page that indicate the plural form "staff". I've edited the first sentence of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to make better research next time, before posting :)